# REST Jersey Tomcat 7

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, restful-architecture

Getting 404 error, when accessing the

Hello.java

```
package de.vogella.jersey.first;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

} 
'
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>de.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

This has been taken from the http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html, but when I run the 
`http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello`

. I get 404 error .

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I've completed this tutorial, and successfully launched your example.

My tip: tutorial you are trying to complete is 4-years old, so is not so actual. Better download full working example with jersey 2.0.

Your possible errors:

1. Firstly you need `jersey-archive-1.16` version. Jersey's new version
   no longer contains class `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` which you are refering to inside **web.xml**
2. Secondly: make sure your application's **context-root** is really set to `de.vogella.jersey.first`. If you're using eclipse check file: `org.eclipse.wst.common` and its `context-root` parameter.
3. And of course make sure your project compiles correctly and on the classpath are at least four jars: *asm.jar, jersey-core.jar, jersey-server.jar, jersey-servlet.jar*.

Comment: Above coding context root is correct find Coding package name and web.xml

Comment: @Boopathi, doesn't have to be correct. During project creation inside eclipse, `context-root` is automatically being set to the project name. So this can also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am just providing more info over Grzesiek D, which helped me fix ths issue.

1. jersey-archive-1.16 version. Jersey's new version
   no longer contains class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer which you are refering to inside web.xml
2. make sure your application's context-root is really set to de.vogella.jersey.first. If you're using eclipse check file: org.eclipse.wst.common and its context-root parameter.

***To change the context-rrot to match the package of your project:

(i) In your project's Properties, choose "Web Project Settings".

(ii) Change "Context root" to "app". screen shot of Eclipse project properties Web Project Settings

(iii) Choose Window > Show View > Servers.

(iv) Stop the server by either clicking the red square box ("Stop the server" tooltip) or context-click on the server listing to choose "Stop".

(v)On the server you want to use, context-click to choose "Clean…"

(vi) Click OK in this confirmation dialog box. *******************

1. And of course make sure your project compiles correctly and on the classpath are at least four jars: asm.jar, jersey-core.jar, jersey-server.jar, jersey-servlet.jar.